# Bind a lookup field to a dropdown in Provider Hosted App SharePoint Online using CSOM/C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, provider-hosted-app, dropdown

I am trying to bind a lookup column named team to an asp.net dropdown and the dropdown renders blank

**HTML**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="team" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**CSOM**

```
private void FetchTeam()
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/test"))
                {

                    string login = "*****";
                    string password = "******";
                    SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();

                    foreach (char c in password)

                    { securepassword.AppendChar(c); }



                    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securepassword);

                    Web site = ctx.Web;
                    List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee");
                    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
                    ctx.Load(collection);

                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in collection)
                    {
                        string text = string.Format("{0}", item.FieldValues["Team"]);
                        eid.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(text, item.Id.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All the articles here are for SharePoint Server SSOM.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use the below code snippet for assign ***Team*** Look-up column value in the drop-down.

```
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in collection)
{
    FieldLookupValue lookup = item["Team"] as FieldLookupValue;
    string lvalue = lookup.LookupValue;
    int lId = lookup.LookupId; // If need to bind the look-up column field value's ID in the drop-down as ID then use this.

    eid.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(lvalue, item.Id.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Hi Divya , This seems to be working as expected :) Thanks a lot. Since I am new to SharePoint Dev , do you have any article that focusses on basic CRUD operations using CSOM in SharePoint Online? any help would be appreciated. If you want me to post this as separate question please let me know.

Comment: Hello Vivek, please refer the below links for some basics operation through CSOM:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/create-update-delete-a-list-using-client-object-model-cso/

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-net-client-object-model-examples/

Comment: Thanks for the help Divya , would surely take a look :)

Comment: Hi Divya , came across another issue pertaining to saving values to a lookup column from a dropdown , would appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks :)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293613/insert-a-value-from-a-dropdown-to-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint-online-using-cso

Comment: Hello Vivek, I have provided my response on the above question. Please have a look on it.