# Insert a value from a dropdown to a lookup column in SharePoint Online using CSOM/C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, provider-hosted-app, dropdown

I have a dropdown with values from a column named **Title(Single line of text)**

The end goal is to store these values from the dropdown to a **lookup column named Team.**

Read a few articles here , However did not find a resolution to my issue.

**C# Code**

```
private void AddEmployee()
        {
            try
            {
                string login = "******";
                string password = "******";
                SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in password)

                { securepassword.AppendChar(c); }

                ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/test");
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securepassword);
                Web site = ctx.Web;
                List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee");
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                var items = list.GetItems(query);
                ctx.Load(items);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (var oListItem in items)
                 {    

                    oListItem["Title"] = txtName.Text.ToString();
                    oListItem["Age"] = txtAge.Text;
                    oListItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
                    FieldLookupValue lookup = oListItem["Team"] as FieldLookupValue;
                lookup.LookupId = team.SelectedIndex;
                oListItem["Team"] = lookup;
                    oListItem.Update();
                    
                }

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully...');", true);
            }
            catch (ApplicationException ex)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "Error Occured" + ex.Message, true);
            }
        }
```

The code runs without any errors , However no data is saved to the respective columns.

Would appreciate if anyone could assist me.

**Update**

Modified the code as below , However no values are saved

```
FieldLookupValue lookup = oListItem["Team"] as FieldLookupValue;
lookup.LookupId = team.SelectedIndex;
oListItem["Team"] = lookup;
```

Also wrote the `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` before `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully...');", true);` and got the error

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
> the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
> requested.

Comment: After the "oListItem.Update();" do you ctx.ExecuteQuery() your updates?

Comment: @dinos.kon , I tried that too and it gives me an error "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` after updating items.

Try adding `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` **before** this line:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully...');", true);
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh , thank you for responding. I tried this and it gives an error

"The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below code snippet for setting the look-up field value:

```
foreach (var oListItem in items)
{    
    oListItem["Title"] = txtName.Text.ToString();
    oListItem["Age"] = txtAge.Text;
    oListItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
    
    FieldLookupValue lookup = oListItem["Team"] as FieldLookupValue;
    lookup.LookupId = lID; // assign the selected value of the drop-down Team
    oListItem["Team"] = lookup;
    oListItem.Update();
}
```

---

Edit:

```
private void AddEmployee()
{
    try
    {
        string login = "******";
        string password = "******";
        SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password)
        { securepassword.AppendChar(c); }

        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/test");
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securepassword);
        Web site = ctx.Web;
        List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee");
        
        ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();  
        ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(listCreationInformation);  
        
        oListItem["Title"] = txtName.Text.ToString();
        oListItem["Age"] = txtAge.Text;
        oListItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        FieldLookupValue lookup = oListItem["Team"] as FieldLookupValue;
        lookup.LookupId = team.SelectedIndex;
        oListItem["Team"] = lookup;
        oListItem.Update();  
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
        
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully...');", true);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "Error Occured" + ex.Message, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Divya ,thanks for responding , Tried the steps suggested by you , However no data is getting saved to the list. I am updating my question , Kindly check

Comment: Hello Vivek, I have updated my answer please check after "Edit".

Comment: Hi Divya , I've tried this before and it gives me the error "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested". Also it does not allow me to write 
ListItem oListItem =list.AddItem(listCreationInformation); . Replaced it with
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(listCreationInformation);

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM? If not, then please refer the article for which NuGet package to use for Online. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/using-correct-csom-version-for-sharepoint-customizations/